# How to restrict the number of continuous or consecutive swipes

Tags: iphone, ipad, navigation, swipe

i am developing a book reader on ipad. i am using the swipe gesture to navigate to the next page. But my app is getting hanged on crashed when i try to navigate (swipe) at a fast pace. So, is there any way to restrict the number of continuous or consecutive swipes…??? 
Please help with me with your inputs. They will help me go a long way in my project. Thankyou

Comment: You should fix the bug, it's really annoying if swipes are ignored. And from my experience there are ways to trigger the same bug without swiping. Be happy that you can trigger it easily, and fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could throttle the number of swipes you are handling by skipping say every third swipe or so). However, that would just add frustration for the user, as they'll be swiping and nothing would be happening. And if you actually go that route, at least add a wait cursor, so that the user is aware the app is busy.

However, you really should figure out why the app is crashing (or hanging - not clear from your question) and fix it. If the user wants to leaf quickly through the pages, you should let them.

Comment: Hi franci and flutchtpunkt.. thank you for ur answers... i understand that restricting the swipes will annoy the user.. We are trying hard to figure out a longterm solution... but i'v got a urgent demo wer in i should not let the app crash. So, please tell me how i can restrict the swipes... Thankyou

Comment: When you start processing the first swipe, set a flag, and don't process any more swipes until you finish the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag that keeps track of when you are paging.  When you swipe, only trigger the paging mechanism if the flag is NO, and immediately set it to YES when paging.  When your paging mechanism finishes, set it back to NO.